# What do you need to do to create a single package for blackberry OS5 and OS6 devices?

Tags: blackberry

A newb question and one I haven't been able to see much advice on, but is it possible to create a single package that will install and run on both blackberry OS5 and OS6 devices?

I want to avoid preprocessing or creation of two different COD files.

I am not using anything special that differs between the two OS's (afaik!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  So far, RIM has made all of it's OS revisions backwards-compatible.  So anything you write against any given OS version will work on that version and all newer versions.

That's not to say that you won't run into funny quirks when moving to newer OS versions, but your code will execute without recompilation.  You just can't take advantage of any of the newer OS's API changes without doing preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Basically in this case you just should not use APIs which were added in OS6.